# Access directory listing in chrome file:// URI applicaton

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I am developing an application which will work under `file://` URI for safety reasons. It needs to link to other files in my computer as well as read content of some directories.

While reading specific files seems simple, I am unable to find a way to read directory listing. Is there any way to do this.

I have a local web server installed which can be used as a proxy for directory listing. But I ideally don't want to use this approach

Note: I don't want to develop it as Chrome extension, or use a sandbox filesystem. I need to read directory listing of any folder present

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple program if you have or can install a local web server.

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null');

$key = "very_long_key";
if (isset($_GET['dir'], $_GET['key']) && is_dir($_GET['dir']) && $_GET['key'] == $key) {
    $dir = $_GET['dir'];
    $files = glob($dir . '\*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,webm,mp4}', GLOB_BRACE);
    echo json_encode($files);
} else {
    var_dump($_GET);
}
```

You can use AJAX to make request to it. But still I am looking for a way to do it without need of a web server if anybody knows